# How can i change the name of checkbox each time it iterates over while loop?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to generate a checkbox for all results from database for which the condition was matched .

I was abled to do that , now I would like to take that data from checkbox and insert into database , its for a voting project I am working on , I am not sure how I could achieve this because there's no specific name for the checkboxes to get data from .

I am new to this area and really lost.

If someone could help its much appreciated.

```
private void loadCandidates()
{
    String qry = "SELECT * FROM candidate_tb WHERE party ='Samagi Jana Balawegaya'";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            String no = (rd["no"].ToString());//Getting candidate no
            CheckBox check = new CheckBox();//creating new checkbox
            check.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 10);
            check.Text = no + "candidate";
            check.Name ="btn1"+i;
            FLP.Controls.Add(check);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Internal error: {es}");
    }
}

private void voteCast()
{
    //where the casted vote data would go to database  
    //but I cant seem to find a way
}
```

Comment: You tagged your question as "asp.net", but you use a `MessageBox`. Are you sure that this is about a web application? If it isn't, please remove the tag and replace it with the appropriate UI technology (probably WinForms or WPF).

Comment: Checkbox probably had a listener on it that responds to onpresssded or onchecked where you might save off the last thing the he checked on that you could then use on vote cast.

Comment: *"there's no specific name for the checkboxes to get data from"*, well, you *do* have a name, it's `"btn1" + i`, you set it yourself. That having been said, the most elegant solution is probably to store your (id, checkbox) pairs in a list or dictionary.

Comment: You can get the control back with `var checkBox = (CheckBox)FLP.Controls["button_name"];`